# Why I am facing error while installing Nodemon?

Tags: npm-install

Last login: Sun Sep 19 13:02:00 on ttys000
navarajgiri@Navarajs-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm i nodemon

added 120 packages, and audited 121 packages in 708ms

11 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
navarajgiri@Navarajs-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install -g nodemon

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.nodemon-SfftGed4
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.nodemon-SfftGed4'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.nodemon-SfftGed4'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.nodemon-SfftGed4'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/navarajgiri/.npm/_logs/2021-09-19T04_04_27_310Z-debug.log
navarajgiri@Navarajs-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use npm with the -g (global mode) option which implies system-wide install, and this requires permission (`EACCESS`) to do so.  Either install it in local mode (without -g) possible in a `virtuaelenv` or run the command as root (via `sudo`}) as suggested.